# Chrome Issue - AJAX Inserted File Input not uploading file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form where a file input field is being dynamically inserted via AJAX.  Essentially what I'm doing is displaying a form, the user picks which template they want, and I pull in some extra form fields depending on the template they chose.  One of them has a file input.  The problem is when I go to submit the form with the added file input, the PHP $_FILES array is giving me an error code of 4, meaning there wasn't a file uploaded.  Does anyone know what I need to do to get these files uploading?

I'm guessing I have to do something on the JS side to re-evaluate which form fields I'm sending, but I haven't been able to find anything.  (and yes I'm using proper enctype on the form.)

Update : This is only happening on Safari/Chrome.  I read elsewhere that they think this is a security feature of webkit browsers.  I don't know if there is a fix for this..

Thanks all

Comment: Update: this is only happening in Chrome.  In IE/Firefox I can see the URL was POST'ed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you are using a $.post or form.submit(). If you are using form.submit() there might be something else going wrong.

Otherwise, in order to send files to the server via AJAX you need to use the [Form Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) object.

This MDN Page [Using FormDataObjects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Using_FormData_objects) has good examples on how to use it. Note that if you use jQuery you need to set processData and contentType to false. See Below (taken from the MDN page).

```
var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("fileinfo"));
fd.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");
$.ajax({
  url: "stash.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: fd,
  processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
  contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
});
```

Comment: I'm not sending the files themselves via AJAX.  I'm just bringing in the input fields and planting them in the <form> itself.  Then it's just a regular POST form submission.

Comment: then you might want to post some code so that people can help. If you haven't used it http://jsfiddle.net/ is a really good place to post your code.

Answer (score 0):

if you send the form via a form.submit() method, there should be no problem sending files. Are you trying to send your files via ajax ? if so you cant directy. use an iframe, flash or read the file datas with a FileReader and send raw datas in your ajax request.

Comment: I'm not trying to send the files themselves via AJAJX. I'm just bringing in the input fields and planting them in <form> itself.  Then it's just a regular POST form submission.